# How to mint a smart contract in "phases"?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nft

I just started learning Solidity to develop smart contracts for an NFT project, and have run into a roadblock I can't seem to understand.

The goal is to mint in several phases (e.g. allow for minting 100 tomorrow, 100 more the next week, and the last 100 the week after). How would I go about doing this?

Keep in mind I do not want the NFTs to be "sniped", and after minting the first 100 I want to reveal NFT pictures, so I am afraid that this reveal will make the IPFS link public and that people can easily see what pictures they can mint in the next phase?

Not sure if I make any sense, and sorry for being a noob, but please let me know if you want me to clarify and thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do your mint in phases.  There are plenty of projects out there that have this type of mint structure already:
Phase 1: Reserved Mint (number to mint for giveaways)
Phase 2: Presale (number to mint to WL members)
Phase 3: Public (number to mint to public members)

In your case each phase would just be p1,p2,p3 and the number allowed to mint in each phase would be 100.

From what I know, there is no good way to reveal the images in phases though.  As soon as you update the `tokenURI` it will be changed for all images.  Even if you did reveal them in phases somehow, the ipfs link would be public which means anyone could see where the rare ones are located.

My first suggestion would be to look at the contracts of projects that you want yours to be modeled after on etherscan.  These will typically give you the best start as to how you will want to structure your contract.

If you need any more help I'm always available on Twitter @_syndk8